# Google Place API, jQuery showing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: jquery, api, undefined

I'm trying to use Google Place API to display Name, Address of the business and a link to html_attributions in photos(JSON). The page is showing first two options (Name and Address) however it doesn't display html_attributes. It comes back with "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined".
How do I go about fixing the issue?

[image]

Here's the code.

```
const googleBtnEl = $("#googleBtn");
const googleDivEl = $("#googleDiv");

$(googleBtnEl).on("click", function () {
    googleDivEl.empty();
    console.log("Google Map");

    $.ajax("/api/events/cars").done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        
        for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            // working!
            const name = $("<p>").text(response[i].name);
            googleDivEl.append(name);
            
            // working!
            const address = $("<p>").text(response[i].formatted_address);
            googleDivEl.append(address);
            
            // NOT working.....
            const link = $("<a>").attr("href",JSON.stringify(response[i].photos[0].html_attributions[0]));
            googleDivEl.append(link);

        }
    });
    
});
```

api-routes

```
app.get("/api/events/cars", function(req, res) {
    axios.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=car+events&key=" + process.env.API_KEY).then(function(response) {
        res.json(response.data.results);
```

Google API JSON
[image]

Comment: Do all the results have a photo?

Comment: Some do and some don't.

Comment: So how can you access it if it does not have one? You need to check to see if it exists before you access it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I did actually add an if statement in the function and it's showing up as it should!